# How to add method to class without creating new class that extends it.

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I'm wondering if there's a way to add a method to  class without creating a new class and extending it.

For instance. I have a class like this.

```
class GithubApi {
  constructor() {
  } 
}
```

With some basic functionally.

However then I want to add a method to this function and make it extensible.

Is there a way to do that without extending from it?

```
class GithubApiExtra extends GithubApi {
  constructor() {
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`class` is syntax sugar for prototypes, you can still do the same as you'd do before classes:

```
GithubApi.prototype.method = function() {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi for adding a method a object in javascript

    `yourObject.youfun=new function(a,b){
      return a*b 
    };`

there is no class in javascript . there are object constructored form a method

like

```
  function Person()
       {
        var T=new Object(); 
         T.name='Po';
         T.age=12;
         return T;
        }
```

Update:
But there are classes in ECMASCRIPT 6 
class supported in chrome 42+,Firefox 45+,edge 13+
ie and opera not supported it

```
    class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

adding method to polygon=

```
Polygon.prototype.fun= function(a){return a*a};
```

Comment: There is class syntax in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: sorry ... i dont know it  but i think come in ECMA6(2015) [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#6th_Edition